# Issues when rendering variable values into HTML using @

Tags: razor, asp.net-webpages

In an ASP.NET Web Pages (not Web Forms, not MVC) file I had the following two lines:

```
<p class="h1"><a href="#collapse_@i" aria-controls="collapse_@i">@i</a></p>
<div id="collapse_@i" class="row collapse in">
```

The first line would render as `<p class="h1"><a href="#collapse_@i" aria-controls="collapse_@i">@i</a></p>` - ie. the two `@i` would not render the value of the variable `i` (an int).

And the second line would result in the following error:

> The code block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

The problem was easily fixed by wrapping brackets around the variable, eg. `@(i)`, but I wonder why they didn't render or caused a 500 error show when used as a HTML elements `ID`?